# redshift not working as intended

Tags: kali-linux, redshift

I am using Kali Linux and to filter the blue light, I am using this command:

```
redshift -O 3500
```

But after a minute or so, the screen again goes back to default (does not filter the blue light anymore). Is it because `redshift` does not work during the day (and if it is so, how can I make it work during the day) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user configuration file shall be located in:

```
~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf
```

---

If not existing, create it, or edit to your liking.

---

Example with my GPS redacted, including some more notes from me:

```
[redshift]

; Global settings file for Redshift application.

; Location provider for solar elevation.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue2' or 'manual'.
; The actual provider settings are in a separate section.
location-provider=manual


; Smooth fade between temperatures when Redshift starts and stops.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; 0 causes an immediate change between screen temperatures.
; 1 gradually applies the new screen temperature over a couple of seconds.
fade=0


; Solar elevation thresholds.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; By default, Redshift will use the current elevation of the sun to determine
; whether it is daytime, night or in transition (dawn / dusk). When the sun is
; above the degrees specified with elevation-high it is considered daytime and
; below elevation-low it is considered night.
;elevation-high=3
;elevation-low=-6


; Day and night screen temperatures.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Default temperatures in K (Kelvin):
; Day time   : 6500
; Night time : 4500
temp-day=7500
temp-night=5500


; Custom dawn / dusk times.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Instead of using the solar elevation, the time intervals of dawn and dusk can
; be specified manually. The times must be specified as HH:MM in 24-hour format.
;dawn-time=05:00
;dusk-time=16:00


; The adjustment method: 'randr', 'vidmode'.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; This has changed since the 1.12 version in favor of randr,
; formerly vidmode has mostly been used from what I read.
adjustment-method=randr


; Manual GPS of the location for solar elevation.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Standard longitude and latitude coordinates.
[manual]
lat=xx.8111306
lon=yy.1414300


; Adjustment method settings.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so 1 is actually the second screen.
; This actually works for all monitors, needs clarification!
[randr]
screen=0
```

---

Afterward, I suggest running it from your shell in verbose mode (`-v`) to possibly debug issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install required packages using below command:

   sudo apt install redshift geoclue-2.0
2. Find your location Latitude / Longitude using below URL:

   https://geotargetly.com/my-ip-geolocation
3. Redshift usage:
   redshift-gtk -l Latitude:Longitude -t Day_temperature:Night_temperature
4. Open Terminal and type below command, changing your latitude:longitude and temperature as per your requirement. Ex:

   sudo redshift-gtk -l 266.727101:108.395286 -t 4000:3400
5. Close the terminal